# Is it haram to buy from the brand Versace because the logo is a Greek mythological figure?

Tags: halal-haram, image, adornments

Asslamu 3leykum my question is if it is allowed to buy from the brand Versace. I have been wanting to buy a fragrance from Versace but I’m not sure if it is haram or halal because it has the logo of Versace who is a Greek mythological figure by the name of Medusa and her face is on it so I wondered if i could buy it and just cover it? In’sha’Allah yall can answer me

Comment: Why should itbe haram?